# How do i set Query connection timeout in Oracle Pro*C file

Tags: c, linux, timeout, oracle-pro-c

I need to set specific query connection timeout in oracle pro*c.
For example in java, the queryobj.settimeout(*timeoutvalue*); will set that specific timeoutvalue to the query(say select/insert/delete/update) and if the query takes more time than the specific value, .

Similarly i need to implement for pro*c queries.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to alter the user profile.

```
EXEC SQL 
 ALTER PROFILE CTPROFILE2 
 LIMIT 
 SESSIONS_PER_USER Unlimited
 CPU_PER_SESSION 2000
 CPU_PER_CALL Unlimited
 CONNECT_TIME 2
 IDLE_TIME 30
 LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION Unlimited
 LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL Unlimited
 COMPOSITE_LIMIT Unlimited
 PRIVATE_SGA Unlimited
 FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS Unlimited
 PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME Unlimited
 PASSWORD_REUSE_TIME Unlimited
 PASSWORD_REUSE_MAX Unlimited
 PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME Unlimited
 PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME Unlimited
 PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION NULL 
;
```

The above shows most of the settings, check your documentation for exactly what you want.  I am guessing you want to limit cpu.  I picked 2000 out of thin air.
This ALTER statement assumes the profile already exists.

Comment: can we use millisecs as well in the cpu_per_session? in my app i need to set a timeout for 200msec.

Comment: You did not specify earlier.  The units are 1/100th of a second of cpu.  So use CPU_PER_SESSION 20.  But.  This is the total for the session.  You get logged out if you hit the limit.  Consider CPU_PER_CALL which may be what you want for a given call for a resultset. This simply stops the query I believe.